# Where does the Olive Branch (KOLV) class D ceiling meet the Memphis (KMEM) class B floor?

Tags: airspace, class-b-airspace, class-d-airspace

[image]

I'm having an internal debate on interpreting the Class D ceiling in part of the the Memphis TAC. My understanding was in the case of a Class D under a Class B shelf, the ceiling of the Class D ends at the floor of the Bravo, or in this case: 1,800ft MSL.

However, the [29] box printed inside the area of the Class B/D is causing  confusion. Is this explicitly stating the Class D does extend to 2,900ft MSL or does it end at 1,800ft MSL as I originally thought?

Comment: As has been noted in a comment, this question could use some clarification to indicate that you are only asking about the part of the Class D airspace that is charted as appearing to underlie a Class B shelf with a 1800' MSL floor (if you are).  However, I see you have not been active on ASE since this question was posted, so...

Comment: PS I think the fact that they chose to put the boxed "29" numeral in the western part of the Class D airspace rather than the eastern part is of no consequence whatsoever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Class D airspace surrounding the Olive Branch airport extends upward to 2900 feet msl, excluding the Class B airspace.  So, your understanding is  correct.

Here is the official description of this Class D airspace from [FAA Order 7400.11,](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400_11A.pdf)  Airspace Designations and Reporting Points: (emphasis is mine)

> **ASO MS D Olive Branch, MS
>   Olive Branch Airport, MS**
>   (lat. 34º58'44"N., long. 89º47'13''W.)
>
> That airspace extending upward from the surface to and including 2,900 feet MSL within a
>   4-mile radius of Olive Branch Airport; **excluding that airspace within the Memphis Class B
>   airspace area**. This Class D airspace area is effective during the specific days and times established in advance by a Notice to Airmen. The effective days and times will thereafter be continuously published in the Airport/Facility Directory.
>
> AMENDMENTS 04/15/04 69 FR 5009 (Added)

Comment: Three are two different class B shelves involved. The one directly over OLV doesn't start until 3000. So the D ceiling is 2900 there. But the section of B closer to MEM are down to 1800 ft, so the D ceiling drops down with it to <1800 ft

Comment: I used to teach out of KOLV, and the only NASA Report I've ever filed was for accidentally busting the MEM B airspace. So I will concur. If you fly west of Olive Branch, you better be low.

Comment: This answer is not inconsistent w/ the comment from TomMcW, but it could be clarified to make the point more clearly--